Disable visual studio from auto adding . gitattributes file to commit
Cant disable .gitattribute file from being added to my commits
After creating a new repo from the vs git tab im forced to push one commit to remote containing a .gitattribute file before every other commits And than when im trying to push commits to remote a .gitattribute file is added to my commits again.
is there a way to disable vs from automatically adding this file?

Deleting it? Otherwise you really should push it.
